# Ruby infinite while true ends silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I start a script `simple.rb` with `ruby simple.rb > log.txt &`. I want it to run infinitely. It runs for a while, but `pidof ruby` does not return anything. The script stops running, and there is no error code or exit msg in the log file. What happened? Do ruby loops end eventually? I can restart the ruby script when it ends from a bash endless loop, but I'm curious as to why this script ends, and how I can find out if it doesn't emit an exit code/msg.

```
def main_loop
  puts "Doing stuff.."
end

while true
  main_loop
  sleep 5.seconds
end
```

Comment: What are your `ruby --version` and `bash --version`? You must be missing something, as `5.seconds` is not defined in ruby - it's a Rails addition. On my machine, your code quickly raises `undefined method `seconds' for 5:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: I'm pulling in rails additions: `require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)` running the script from within a `railsapp/lib` folder

Comment: `ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: `bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Please post the exact and full script you're running, so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `#seconds` is unnecessary and is probably messing up your code, since `#sleep` takes a number (float or integer, I believe). See http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep .

```
$stdout.sync = true
def main_loop
  puts "Doing stuff.."
end

while true
  main_loop
  sleep 5
end
```

Comment: I just confirmed that the `seconds` was wrong since your code wouldn't run once, let alone loop in it's original form. I'm currently running my version as a background processes. It's been looping correctly for several minutes now, however, it wouldn't write to the logfile until I added $stdout.sync = true to flush output immediately.